# Validity of US5481539

Tags: us5481539

Is this patent Valid and which countries it is?
Can I realize an application that create a communication between two mobile phone using radio waves and sell it on android or iOs?
Do I have to pay some fees?Do I need any kind of agreement?

Answer (score 1):

The patent has expired (lapsed back in 2000).